# Python: list comprehensions vs. lambda

Tags: python, list, lambda, list-comprehension

I want to retrieve the integer value from the sublist containing "b" as the first element (b will only appear once in the list)

Those two ways came to my mind:

```
foo = [["a", 5], ["b", 10], ["c", 100]]

y = filter(lambda x: x[0] == "b", foo)
print y[0][1]

z = [foo[i][1] for i in range(len(foo)) if foo[i][0] == "b"] 
print z[0]
```

They both work. Is any of the two preferable (regarding runtime), is there an even better third way?

Comment: `z = [x[1] for x in foo if x[0] == 'b']` is somewhat cleaner even.

Comment: Or `[b for a, b in foo if a == 'b']`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When the list is so small there is no significant difference between the two. If the input list can grow large then there is a worse problem: you're iterating over the whole list, while you could stop at the first element. You could accomplish this with a for loop, but if you want to use a comprehension-like statement, here come *generator expressions*:

```
# like list comprehensions but with () instead of []
gen = (b for a, b in foo if a == 'b')
my_element = next(gen)
```

or simply:

```
my_element = next(b for a, b in foo if a == 'b')
```

If you want to learn more about generator expressions give a look at [PEP 289](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

---

Note that even with generators and iterators you have more than one choice.

```
# Python 3:
my_element = next(filter(lambda x: x[0] == 'b', foo))

# Python 2:
from itertools import ifilter
my_element = next(ifilter(lambda (x, y): x == 'b', foo))
```

I personally don't like and don't recommend this because it is much less readable. It turns out that this is actually slower than my first snippet, but more in general using `filter()` instead of a generator expression might be faster in some special cases.

In any case if you need benchmarking your code, I recommend using [the `timeit` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html).

Comment: `next(v for k,v in foo if k == "b")` -- using `next()` rather than `.next()` -- is more forward-compatible.

Comment: In my timings, the `ifilter` version loses if it has to check more than two items.

Comment: Out of interest: where can you read up that separating two variables by commas is a way to access elements of a list in a for-loop?
This was new to me and I find it quite useful. I only knew 
`my_element = next(x[1] for x in foo if x[0] == 'b')`
till now

Comment: @HelmHammerhand it is called unpacking and it's documented here: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements but you can use similar forms in for loops (as above) and function arguments lists (like the lambda above)

Answer (score 4):

This is slower than DavidE's answer (I timed it), but has the advantage of simplicity:

```
z = dict(foo)['b']
```

Of course it assumes that your keys are all hashable, but that's fine if they are strings.
If you need to do multiple lookups though this is definitely the way to go (just be sure to only convert to a dict once).

Comment: +1 for the simplicity, but I don't think this would speed things up as it requires a full iteration over the sequence. If speed is the problem, I would benchmark (and profile), as it depends on many things (size of the list, memory requirements, hash collisions) depending on the input.

Comment: @DavideR. I timed it, and for lists up to about 10,000 elements your solution is about the same speed if it's the last element or twice as fast on average. For a 100,000 element list you get to about 4 times faster on average.